# Liquibase assuming '--' as start of comment even when it is inside quotes as part of my query

Tags: oracle, liquibase

I want to execute the following query:

`COMMENT ON COLUMN "MY_TABLE"."COLUMN" IS 'A--> Active X--> In-Active';`

Liquibase fails as it assumes everything after -- as comment and ignores it.

Is there a way to override this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a bug, and will need to be reported to the maintainers.